# For a finite field $F$ of order $n$, all elements are roots of $x^n - x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields

I need to prove two things at $F[X]$ but don't know how, Ill glad to get help...

$F$ is a finite field.
$|F|=n$. We look at $p(x)=x^n-x\in F[X]$
1. How we can show that every $c\in F$ is a root of $p(x)$ (Lagrange Theorem).
2. $p(x)=\prod_{c\in F}(x-c)$

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints**:

(1) The multiplicative group $F^\times$ is a finite group of order $n - 1$. This gives $x^{n-1} = 1$ for all $x \in F - \{0\}$ by Lagrange's theorem.

(2) In the polynomial ring over a field $F$, if $c \in F$ is a root of $x^n - x$, then $x - c$ divides $x^n - x$.

Comment: Note  $\, x=\pm1, \pm3\, $ are roots of $\,x^2-1\,$ over $\,\Bbb Z/8\,$ but $\,x^2-1 \neq (x-1)(x+1)(x-3)(x+3).$ So while the rest may be "easy", it is *essential* to say *why* it is true in this ring (since it may fail in other rings).

Comment: Thank you Ayman Hourieh!! You can give me ideas for the 2nd?

Comment: @YoavFridman Added another hint.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for your comment. I've expanded my hint a little bit. Indeed, the fact that we're working over a field is crucial.

Comment: @Ayman I'm afraid that is still not enough since the counterexample I gave satisfies that property (indeed the factor theorem is true in every ring).

Comment: @AymanHourieh, every polynomial at $F[X]$ have a different roots, no? so I don't understand, how you can define this specific polynomial ($x^{n-1}$)? Every polynomial has a different roots...

Comment: @BillDubuque $\Bbb Z /(8)[x]$ isn't even an integral domain. I understand that my hint doesn't spell out all of the ingredients for a proof. This is why it's labeled as a hint.

Comment: @Ayman Right, but I think it is essential to explicitly mention that, since it is crucial ingredient in the proof.

Comment: @BillDubuque I really don't want to argue over hint etiquette. I think the current answers combined give more than enough to properly answer the question. :)

Comment: @YoavFridman I consider $x^{n-1} - 1$ in particular because multiplying it by $x$ gives the polynomial in the question.

Comment: @Ayman Apologies if my comment seems a bit too pedantic. The point was merely to make clear to the OP (and readers) that one needs to use some special properties of the ring (not only the Factor Theorem). Bringing these properties to the foreground helps students avoid mistakes further down the line (and this is at the heart of one common class of mistakes that I see frequently).

Comment: @Bill No problem at all. Issues like this continue to make me question the value of hints vs. full solutions. I sometimes dislike giving hints because of such issues. But the common consensus here seems to be "hints for easy questions." Of course, one person's "easy" isn't easy at all for someone else.

Comment: Another way to "solve" the problem @Bill mentioned is to note that when working over a field (or in general an integral domain), the process of "factoring out" roots using the factor theorem until a polynomial with no roots is obtained gives *all* the roots of the original polynomial. (Show that if we write $p(x) = (x-a_1)(x-a_2)\dots(x-a_n)q(x)$ where $q(x)$ has no root in $R$, the existence of a root of $p(x)$ which is not one of the $a_i$ gives a contradiction.)

Comment: @Ayman Yes, I agree that choosing between hints vs. full answers is tricky. Without much context, it is difficult to know how much detail to give, what subtleties to highlight, etc. E.g. while many students will encounter rings with zero-divisors such as $\,\Bbb Z/m,\,$ many may never work in non-associative rings, so it would be a distraction to emphasize where associativity plays a role (almost everywhere here).

Comment: @AymanHourieh, but we are talking about $F$, not $F^\times$...

Comment: And there is no problem from passing from $F\to F^\times$?

Comment: Well $F^\times = F - \{0\}$, so when we multiply $x^{n-1} - 1$ by $x$, we get a polynomial that is satisfied by all $x \in F$, including $0$.

Comment: @AymanHourieh, I don't understand why, how multiply by $x$ change the field from $F\to F^\times$...

Comment: @AymanHourieh, and one more question: At the second one I don't understand how this helps me to prove it, can you explain more please? Can you give me more details? Because each time $x$ gets one degree less....and what I need to do if I have $(x^{n-3}...)$ for example?

Comment: @YoavFridman Think about it this way: Lagrange's theorem gives $x^{n-1} - 1 = 0$ for all $x \in F - \{0\}$. The relation is still satisfied if we multiply both sides by $x$. This gives $x^n - x = 0$ for all $x \in F - \{0\}$. Now if we plug in $x = 0$, the equation is still satisfied. Thus, $x^n - x = 0$ for all $x \in F$. I'm afraid I can't come up with a simpler explanation!

Comment: @AymanHourieh - You don't have to... you explain it excellent! Now it much more clear :-), If there will something that I still not understand I'll ask..... BTW, can you explain me the other thing? (the 2nd Q).

Comment: @YoavFridman For the second part, if we keep dividing $x^n - x$ by $x - c$ for all $c \in F$, we will get a constant. This is possible because for each $c$, $x - c$ is irreducible, and for different $c_1$, $c_2$, the terms $x - c_1$, $x - c_2$ are not associates. We get a constant in the end because $x^n - x$ has degree $n$ and we have $n$ elements in $F$. The constant must be $1$ since $x^n - x$ is monic (the leading coefficient is $1$).

Comment: @AymanHourieh, Thank you! At the first one, why you have to use $F^\times$? because $p(x)=x^n-x=(x^{n-1}-1)x$ and $p(0)=0$... Thank you!

Comment: @YoavFridman We start with $F^\times$ because we need a group in order to apply Lagrange's theorem. The rest of your comment is correct!

Comment: @AymanHourieh, Thank you! You help me so much!!! I don't understand, why we we have to use $F^\times$? The order of $F$ is finite to...

Answer (score 2):

1) You gave yourself a hint. ;) Apply Lagrange's theorem in the group of units of F.

2) Recall that if $a$ is a root of $p(x)$, then $p(x) = (x-a)q(x)$ for some $q(x)$ whose degree is one less than the degree of $p(x)$.

Comment: For the first one I can say that Because $F$ is finite, for every $a\in F$, $ord(a)\mid |F|$? And this is why every element at $F$ is a root? or I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

Use the hint, [Lagranges' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) to dispatche $(1)\ \ $ (that's quite a big hint!)

By $(1)$ and the Factor Theorem, $\,x^n\!-x$ is disvisible by the nonassociate *primes* $\, x- c,\, $ all $\,c\in F,\,$ therefore it is divisible by their lcm = product. Finally compare degree and lead coefficient.

Comment: But what will be $p(x)$? $x^n$??

Comment: @Yoav The above shows that said product $\,\Pi\,$ divides $\,x^n-x\,$. Clearly they have the same degree and same lead coef $= 1,\,$ hence $\,\ldots$

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain little bit more?

Comment: @Yoav Precisely where are you stuck?

Comment: (+1) This answer fills in some missing details from my hint.